# How to solve npm WARN package.json ... No README data

Tags: node.js, npm

When I run the following command

```
npm install
```

I get the following errors:

```
npm WARN package.json karma-chrome-launcher@0.1.4 No README data
npm WARN package.json karma-coffee-preprocessor@0.2.1 No README data
npm WARN package.json karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.4 No README data
npm WARN unmet dependency /myproj/node_modules/grunt requires lodash@'~0.9.2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /myproj/node_modules/lodash
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.4.1
npm WARN unmet dependency /myproj/node_modules/grunt-usemin requires lodash@'~1.0.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /myproj/node_modules/lodash
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.4.1
grunt-build-control@0.1.3 node_modules/grunt-build-control
└── shelljs@0.2.6
```

What do they mean and how do I resolve them?

Comment: Because the owner of those packages obviously didnt provide a README.MD File within their packages. Since it is just a `WARN`, you can totally ignore that - it doesnt change anything.

Comment: you just get all npm in cmd prompt using npm list. It will show error when you missed any dependency and then you may intall those dependency.

Answer (score 1):

The `README.md` is provided by all of the above projects.

So it is an error on your side. It could very well be that you have saved as dependency, if so you need to change your package.json, but we don't do stuff manually, let `npm` handle it:

### Remove packages from project dependencies

```
npm remove karma-chrome-launcher karma-firefox-launcher karma-cofee-preprocessor karma-phantomjs-launcher --save
```

### Add packages from project devDependecies

Then install as dev dependency as descirbed on the project pages with

```
npm install karma-chrome-launcher karma-firefox-launcher karma-cofee-preprocessor karma-phantomjs-launcher --save-dev
```

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in comments above, these warnings:

```
npm WARN package.json karma-chrome-launcher@0.1.4 No README data
npm WARN package.json karma-coffee-preprocessor@0.2.1 No README data
npm WARN package.json karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.4 No README data
```

are telling you that the maintainer(s) of karma-chrome-launcher, karma-coffee-preprocessor, karma-phantomjs-launcher have not supplied README.md files for their projects.

To solve the problem, you would need to find the package on github and submit a pull request to provide README.md, which the maintainers would probably be happy to accept. ;-)

EDIT: 2015-03-26

`$ npm pack karma-chrome-launcher@0.1.4
    $ tar tzf karma-chrome-launcher-0.1.4.tgz
    package/package.json
    package/LICENSE
    package/index.js`

Comment: The `README.md` is provided by all of the above projects. See my answer.

Comment: If you check the package that's actually present in the repository, you will see that karma-chrome-launcher@0.1.4 **DOES NOT** contain a README.md file (see above)